# Ajax form submit to php for processing on radio button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to make the form submit the data for processor.php to be processed and responses added into a database, but the form is currently not submitting any data.

It is also very important to do this without page refresh, because I have an iframe below the form that should remain untouched.

Here is my form:

```
<form id="myForm" action="" method="post">
    <span id="surveyQuestion">At first glance, how likely it is for you to use the service/product being advertised?</span><br/>
    <span class="info">Not likely</span>
    <input type="radio" name="response" value="0" onClick="this.form.submit()">
    <input type="radio" name="response" value="1" onClick="this.form.submit()">
    <input type="radio" name="response" value="2" onClick="this.form.submit()">
    <input type="radio" name="response" value="3" onClick="this.form.submit()">
    <input type="radio" name="response" value="4" onClick="this.form.submit()">
    <input type="radio" name="response" value="5" onClick="this.form.submit()">
    <span class="info">Very likely!</span>
</form>
```

And here is the jQuery/Ajax:

```
  $(function () {

    $('#myForm').submit(function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'processor.php',
        data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
        success: function () {
          alert('form was submitted');
        }
      });

    });

  });
```

Comment: use `$('#myform').bind('submit', function(){   dataType: 'json', `

Comment: Isn't it so that in your case `this.form.submit()`, this refers to the radio button and not the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Jquery .change()

```js
 $("input.myradio").change(function(){
   alert("hi");
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'processor.php',
        data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
        success: function () {
          alert('form was submitted');
        }
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" action="" method="post">
    <span id="surveyQuestion">At first glance, how likely it is for you to use the service/product being advertised?</span><br/>
    <span class="info">Not likely</span>
    <input type="radio" class="myradio" name="response" value="0" onClick="this.form.submit()">
    <input type="radio" class="myradio" name="response" value="1" onClick="this.form.submit()">
    <input type="radio" class="myradio" name="response" value="2" onClick="this.form.submit()">
    <input type="radio" class="myradio" name="response" value="3" onClick="this.form.submit()">
    <input type="radio" class="myradio" name="response" value="4" onClick="this.form.submit()">
    <input type="radio" class="myradio" name="response" value="5" onClick="this.form.submit()">
    <span class="info">Very likely!</span>
</form>
```

Comment: How do I prevent this from refreshing the whole page?

Comment: remove onClick="this.form.submit()" from the radios

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(function() {

});
```